# Menu navigation bar web page: dynamic menu windows.screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, navigationbar

I want to create a navigation bar menu with a responsive layout.
When the site is displayed on monitors i want dysplay the navigation bar.
When the site is displayed on mobiles i would display the menu icons that display eventually the navigation bar.

How can i do that?

Comment: do want to create responsive navigation  bar ?

Comment: Yes, with an img resized in %. I have the header with fixed position and it show menu, logo and search bar. Everything in %.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, on mobile the navbar will not just display icons but also headings

Just a heads up for next time, there are many tutorials on how to do this sort of things along with helpful websites that could help you to improve on your skills for the future. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.active {
  background-color: #555;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}
</style>
<body>


<div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i> Search</a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Login</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!

I have searched for some tutorials, but i believed it takes more than the part of code with media.